# Spark Sql vs Spark Data frame API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can anyone explain when to use Spark SQL(plain sql queries) and Spark Data Frame methods .I see we can do every operation with spark sql .
Which is better in performance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are both equally performant.

Using dataframe APIs guarantees type safety, and can be further optimized by the SQL engine/query builder

Answer (score 0):

From a usage perspective, it's hard to catch a syntax error until runtime in Spark SQL while using Dataframe APIs we can catch those at compile time.